# Embed Cognito Form so that desktop view is same as mobile layout

Tags: cognito-forms

Our forms will display in a top down easy to use format on mobile phones but if we use the embed code in a page on our website it doesn't display that way.

Is there a way we can still use the embed code on our site and still have the form display correctly on a mobile phone?

Answer (score 1):

All forms in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) are [automatically responsive](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/responsive-forms).  However, if you are embedding them in your website, your website must also be responsive in order for the forms to adapt correctly.

The forms will automatically switch to a narrow single column format suitable for phones when their container drops below 400 logical pixels.  You just need to make sure the containing DIV on your website is allowed to resize and is not a fixed width.